# Do smaller file sizes for webp really make it better than jpeg when rendering speed suffers?

Tags: seo, images, performance, jpeg

Google claims that their WebP format is 25 to 34% lower than the equivalent JPEG quality. But in practice, using it significantly reduces the page rendering speed.

Does it makes sense to sacrifice page load speed for using webp instead of jpeg?

Comment: Does it reduce the render speed because it takes more CPU to decode it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not forever

WebP only performs better with small 500px images. With other image sizes the compression is equal or worse.

Mozilla is also not very optimistic about webp

> WebP and JPEG XR perform better than JPEG according to some quality scoring algorithms, but similarly or worse according to others.

see:[**research.mozilla.org**](https://research.mozilla.org/2013/10/17/studying-lossy-image-compression-efficiency/)